# Combining images into video with ffmpeg, but from multiple folders into the same frames

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have files like so:

```
Trees/000.png
Trees/001.png etc

Clouds/000.png
Clouds/001.png etc

Hill.png
```

I want each frame of the video to be a composite of all 3 images, where `Trees/000.png` will join with `Clouds/000.png` and also have `Hill.png` in the background for each frame.

I could hack my way around this by doing what I know, which would be making a trees video and a clouds video, combining those together, then combining them with the hill - but I think there would be significant quality loss doing it that way so would ideally like to do it all in one go, if possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i Hill.png -i Trees/%03d.png -i Clouds/%03d.png -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=shortest=1[bg];[bg][2]overlay" output.mp4
```

See documentation for [overlay filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) and [image demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) for more info.